# Cannot use MigLayout in Eclipse, but it works in Groovy Console

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy, miglayout

I am using Windows 7, Eclipse 4.2.1 and (trying to use) MigLayout 4.0.

I have downloaded miglayout-4.0-swing.jar, added it to my classpath and succesfully run the following script in Groovy Console:

```
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import groovy.swing.factory.LayoutFactory
import javax.swing.WindowConstants as WC
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout

def swing = new SwingBuilder()
swing.registerBeanFactory('migLayout', MigLayout)

swing.build {
    frame(id: 'eventScrollPanel', pack: true, show: true,
      defaultCloseOperation: WC.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) {
        migLayout(layoutConstraints: "fill, debug", columnConstraints: "",
        rowConstraints: "")
        panel() {
            label(text: "test")
        }
    }
}
```

In Eclipse, I have added the external jar file to my JDK and checked that it appears in Project => Properties => Java Build Path => Libraries tab => JRE System Library [jdk1.7.0_09].  However, the script fails with the following error:

```
Caught: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.miginfocom.layout.UnitValue.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.miginfocom.layout.UnitValue.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at net.miginfocom.layout.PlatformDefaults.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at MigLayoutExamples$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(MigLayoutExamples.groovy:12)
    at MigLayoutExamples$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(MigLayoutExamples.groovy)
    at MigLayoutExamples$_run_closure1.doCall(MigLayoutExamples.groovy:10)
    at MigLayoutExamples$_run_closure1.doCall(MigLayoutExamples.groovy)
    at MigLayoutExamples.run(MigLayoutExamples.groovy:9)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.miginfocom.layout.LayoutUtil.hasBeans(Unknown Source)
    at net.miginfocom.layout.LayoutUtil.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    ... 10 more
```

Also, the migLayout reference at the start of line 12 of the script is underlined by Eclipse, i.e. Eclipse canot resolve the reference.

All help gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this [line](http://code.google.com/p/miglayout/source/browse/core/src/main/java/net/miginfocom/layout/LayoutUtil.java?r=7e186c67e3c8126b72d628f79156cf27c3c75037#70) is the culprit.

```
LayoutUtil.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("java.beans.Beans");
```

The latest jar is 4.2 where this issue seems to have been fixed with a `try-catch` block.
Try with these jars. They are available from Maven repo. http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.miglayout/miglayout-swing/4.2
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.miglayout/miglayout-core/4.2

Comment: Many thanks for your near instant response.  I have changed to V4.2 and the script now works perfectly.  Note that it is necessary to download two jar files from the Maven repo: miglayout-core-4.2.jar and miglayout-swing-4.2.jar.  This is different from V4.0 on the MigLayout web-site which is a single jar file.

Comment: great.!! Go ahead and accept the answer so that other folks know that this is the correct answer. I can update my answer if you can give the me exact two jars.